# auto update of database "id" field

Tags: mysql, database

I am having column with id and news field. The "id" field is showing as primary key in database.

I want the "id" field to be primary only i.e i want it to be incremented by 1. Plus, when i delete any record from this table, it should start counting from deleted number.

Ex:- if i have 20 records. I deleted the record from 10 to 15. As i deleted 5 records, now the total counting is 15 records. Now i want the database to be start from 16 again. But its taking next number i.e record number 21.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thats how the auto incremented works in mysql

Comment: Don't mess with auto increment keys. Just use a datetime column to indicate order

Comment: I implemented auto increment but it starts the values from 21 onwards. but i want it from 15. its not updating according to the record updation..

plus tell me how to avoid null values.. should i use trim function or is their any other to avoid null value. and how to apply NULL to any field. I selected the null option in front of that field but its not working.

Comment: pls tell me how to use datetime column for ordering purpose.

Comment: @user3877861 what is your purpose of having sequence number? would you like to order the records? or would you simply like to have sequenced records?

Comment: @krish KM
yes. I would like to have sequenced records.

Comment: @user3877861 - No, you don't. That is a bad idea. And whatever you'd like to do, there is a nice clean solution for it. Please describe better what are you trying to do and somebody may tell you the nice clean solution for it.

Comment: You can't have sequenced records. You're the millionth person today who assumed wrong that auto_increment gives keys incremented by 1 and reuses them. It doesn't, this is so it can maintain concurrency properly. PK is not for sequences, its job is to uniquely identify a record. Period. It does **nothing else**, it is not there to hand out sequenced numbers. You do not force it to be sequenced. If you do, you are allowing for things to break. You can now either listen to what people have told you and stop trying to mess with it or think you're the smartest one around and do mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add row-count to your rows, just add it in your select, don't mess with auto-increment primary key.

```
SET @pos=1;
SELECT @pos:=@pos+1 AS rowPosition, yourtable.*
  FROM yourtable
  ORDER BY yourtable.id ;
```

This code will print your table with additional row `rowPosition` that numbers your rows 1,2,3,...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do with the sequence numbers but it is possible.
However, no point modifying the auto-numbered column and its not recommended either. Instead you have to insert another column like **sequence_id as int**

then you have to add a trigger to the table like
when a new record is **inserted/deleted** > do initiate the sequence.

the sequence function would be a "check and update function" which checks if the sequence_id is same as the current index position of the row. if not update.

function would look similar to this:

```
set @mIndex :=0;
Update tbl_user
    SET squence_id = (@mIndex := @mIndex + 1)
WHERE ((user_id > 0) and ((tbl_user.squence_id <> @mIndex) or (tbl_user.squence_id is null)));
```

this function will rewrite the sequence number from 0 to your total record count, only when the index position is different.
e.g: if you have sequence id 1 2 3 8 9 6 it will update two rows and the result will be like 1 2 3 4 5 6

be aware this might drastically decrease your DB performance. its totally up to you whether you want to use it or not. this is just demonstrate MySQL is capable of doing such operations.

good luck.